# Reusing Common Functions With Best Correct Approach c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, reusability

I need a Login function(login is just an example, any other frequently used method can be fine) which takes email and password as parameter and asks DB if there is such a user. If yes, it has to return customer_id(int), if no, it will return the message why login could not happen(ex:no such an email address).

I also do not wanna rewrite the login function everytime. I want to write it once in a common project which I can use in my every project and reuse it. But i am trying to find out the best practice for this. So far, i thought something like below, but the problem for me is that i cannot return customerID which i will get in codebehind in my projects(any other project) and open a session variable with it. I only can return strings in below structure. I also thought returning a Dic, but this also is wrong I guess because if bool(key) happens to be true, customerID is not a string(value). Can you help me please learning the correct way of using common functions with no need to think the returning messages and variables twice? Thanks a lot

```
public class UserFunctions
{
    private enum Info
    {
        //thought of returning codes??
        LoginSuccess = 401,
        NoMatchPasswordEmail = 402,
        InvalidEmail = 403,            
    };

    public string TryLogin(string email, string password)
    {
        bool isValidEmail = Validation.ValidEmail(email);
        if (isValidEmail == false)
        {                
            return Result(Info.InvalidEmail);
            // returning a message here
        }        

        Customers customer = new Customers();
        customer.email = email;
        customer.password = password;
        DataTable dtCustomer = customer.SelectExisting();

        if (dtCustomer.Rows.Count > 0)
        {                
            int customerID = int.Parse(dtCustomer.Rows[0]["CustomerID"].ToString());                
            return Result(Info.LoginSuccess);
            // Here I cant return the customerID. I dont wanna open a session here because this function has no such a job. Its other projects button events job I guess
        }
        else
        {                
            return Result(Info.NoMatchPasswordEmail);
        }
    }

    private string Result(Info input)
    {
        switch (input)
        {
            case Info.NoMatchPasswordEmail:
                return "Email ve şifre bilgisi uyuşmamaktadır";
            case Info.InvalidEmail:
                return "Geçerli bir email adresi girmelisiniz";
            case Info.LoginSuccess:
                return "Başarılı Login";
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider returning an instance of a custom class.

```
public class LoginResult
{
    public Info Result { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set;}
}
```

Modify your `TryLogin` method to return an instance of `LoginResult`.

Base your application flow on the result:

```
var loginResult = TryLogin(..., ...);

switch (loginResult.Result)
{
    case Info.LoginSuccess:
        var customerId = loginResult.CustomerId;
        //do your duty
        break;
    case Info.NoMatchPasswordEmail:
        //Yell at them
        break;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Completely forgot about this option. Think i was thinking way too outside the box.

Comment: Then for every function group, you will have to write a custom class. For example, you want a common basket operations class and a add to cart function. You will have to write a custom class with having a orderID this time..

Comment: That to me sounds like a different function altogether, and therefore should require more code.  Above is an example of a generic "log-in", it should be separate from "orders."  Research SOP, Separation of Concerns for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Creating an event and then the calling code can register to the event before attempting to login.
For example:

```
public class UserFunctions
{
    private enum Info
    {
        LoginSuccess = 401,
        NoMatchPasswordEmail = 402,
        InvalidEmail = 403,            
    };

    public delegate void LoginAttemptArgs(object sender, Info result, int CustomerID);//Define the delegate paramters to pass to the objects registered to the event.
    public event LoginAttemptArgs LoginAttempt;//The event name and what delegate to use.

    public void TryLogin(string email, string password)
    {
        bool isValidEmail = Validation.ValidEmail(email);
        if (isValidEmail == false)
        {                
            OnLoginAttempt(Info.InvalidEmail, -1);
        }        

        Customers customer = new Customers();
        customer.email = email;
        customer.password = password;
        DataTable dtCustomer = customer.SelectExisting();

        if (dtCustomer.Rows.Count > 0)
        {                
            int customerID = int.Parse(dtCustomer.Rows[0]["CustomerID"].ToString());
            OnLoginAttempt(Info.LoginSuccess, customerID);
        }
        else
        {                      
            OnLoginAttempt(Info.NoMatchPasswordEmail, -1);
        }
    }
    private void OnLoginAttempt(Info info, int CustomerID)
    {
        if (LoginAttempt != null)//If something has registered to this event
            LoginAttempt(this, info, CustomerID);
    }
}
```

I wouldn't compile a string to return, I would return the enum result and let the calling code do what it likes with the result. reading an enum is much quicker than parsing returned string.

Edit: Typos and i missed an event call... .Twice